# Help eliminating a term inside a square root

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, sums-of-squares

I have the somewhat ugly expression:

$((V_iV_j\lambda_2 + X_iX_j\lambda_1)^2 + \lambda_1\lambda_2(V_iX_j - X_iV_j)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Every single term here is a scalar over the reals.

The goal is to try to isolate that left term in the sum i.e I need to get either:

$((V_iV_j\lambda_2 + X_iX_j\lambda_1)^2)^{0.5} + T$

Where $T$ is some term that makes the expression equal to the one I gave. This is the nicest possible result. If that is not possible then at least something of the form:

$((V_iV_j\lambda_2 + X_iX_j\lambda_1)^2)^{0.5} \cdot T$

Once again $T$ being some expression that makes the claim true.

I have tried and experimented with completing the square and adding 0, multiplying by 1 and similar tricks but I can't find a good way to change the expression into either of the above forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps
\begin{align}
((V_iV_j\lambda_2 + X_iX_j\lambda_1)^2 + \lambda_1\lambda_2(V_iX_j - X_iV_j)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \Big((V_iV_j\lambda_2 + X_iX_j\lambda_1)^2\Big)^{1/2}\left(1 + \frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2(V_iX_j - X_iV_j)^2}{(V_iV_j\lambda_2 + X_iX_j\lambda_1)^2}\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
valid when the first term is non zero.

Comment: This is pretty good, although unfortunately that term can indeed be 0. But I thank you, this is at least better than what I have come up with

Comment: Mabe you can deal with the cases when it zero separately?  You are then only left with the second term.

Comment: If the first term were $0$, you could write: $$ ((V_i V_j \lambda_2 + X_i X_j \lambda_1)^2)^{1/2} + T = T$$ where $$T:= (\lambda_1 \lambda_2 (V_i X_j -X_i V_j)^2)^{1/2}$$

Comment: @ManuelNorman I am not sure how that simplifies the expression tho

Comment: Actually, it doesn't: the expression is exactly the same. However, that way you can obtain an expression in the form you requested even in the case where the first term is $0$. To simplify it, you may use the fact that $$V_i V_j \lambda_2 + X_i X_j \lambda_1 =0$$ which is true because you are dealing with real scalars.